# Как получить id последнего элемента в SQL DB на android?

Tags: android, sql

Собственно есть приложение на android. Подключена база данных. Можно ли как-то получить id последнего элемента в таблице?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 1;
```

или

```
SELECT * 
    FROM    MYTABLE
    WHERE   ID = (SELECT MAX(ID)  FROM TABLE);
```

или вроде такого:

```
String query = "SELECT ROWID from MYTABLE order by ROWID DESC limit 1";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query);
if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
    lastId = c.getLong(0); 
}
```

Comment: Чтобы получить ID достаточно    

    SELECT MAX(ID)  FROM TABLE

Answer (score 2):

В реляционной БД, коей является SQLite, нет понятия первый/последний. Все зависит от способа сортировки/индексирования запроса. Неявно есть, конечно, поле `ROWID`, но даже он не гарантирует, что якобы последний является последней вставкой.

А получить последнюю запись в текущем запросе (с некой заданной сортировкой выдачи) можно через:

```
Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query); //некий запрос
сursor.moveToLast();
```